# How can I keep file pointer in the If clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, if-statement

Could anybody advice me if there is any way to keep file pointer in the nested IF clause.

I have to parse the file, and based on its content, different code blocks should process the file.
I came up with nested IF loops.

The code:

```
import re

with open('smartctl.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = file.readlines()

    for x in line:
        matchIP = re.search('Checking', x)
        if matchIP:
            print(x)
        Match_Micron55 = re.search('Micron_5100', x)
        Match_Intel = re.search('INTEL', x)
        Match_Micron600 = re.search('Micron_M600', x)
        Any_Micron = re.search('Micron', x)
        if Match_Micron55:
            print("here we have Micron55")

        elif Match_Intel:
            print("here we have Intel")

        elif Match_Micron600:
            print('here we have Micron 600')
            mline = line
            print("file is open")
            check = ""
            for y in mline:
                if y == x:
                    check == True
                    continue
                if y.startswith('  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate') and check == True:
                    print(y)
                    continue
                if y.startswith('  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct') and check == True:
                    print(y)
                    continue
                if y.startswith('173 Unknown_Attribute') and check == True:
                    print(y)
                    break
        elif Any_Micron:
            print('Here we have unsorted values')
```

As you can see I read the file as line.
Then I go with variable X through the file.
Then, when I fall in  IF condition, I have to CONTINUE reading the file: that's keep the file pointer and continue reading exactly from the place I went into the IF loop. I use 2 loops here with X and Y variables (for x in line and for y in mline). Could you tell me please if I can continue reading the same file in the second(nested) If confidition?

The method seems to be non working. Apart from creating Y variable I have also tried using X in the nested IF clause but was not succeed. The x (line) variable seems to not keep its value on the second IF entry.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem lies in the following code:

```
line = file.readlines()
    for x in line:
```

The `fileread` is returning a line from the file, the `x in line` is iterating through the line a character at a time.  I bvelieve you should restructure your code as follows:

replace:

```
with open('smartctl.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = file.readlines()

    for x in line:
```

with:

```
with open('smartctl.txt', 'r') as file:
    for x in file.readlines():
```

Comment: Hello Itprorh, Thank you for the attempt. I have tryed your suggestion and, unfortunately, that did not change the picture. It looks like the variable X itself does not keep its value on the second IF condition.

Comment: Can you identify the line where you believe it gores wrong?

Comment: yes, its             for y in mline:
                if y == x:
                    check == True
                    continue

Comment: Okay, you have the instruction ```myline = line``` about  4 lines above. So myline now contains the current file lines.  Then you execute  ```for y in mline:```  which results in y being an iteration of each line in the file.  You then execute ```if y== x: continue``` but you don't have to do that since the line of interest is x.  I am not sure what you are attempting to do in this if,elif sequence?.

Comment: I should also point out, that since x is still within the scope of your ```for x in line:``` clause, and you haven't updated the value of x I doubt it has changed.  You should be able to test this theory by placing a print(x) statement after the ```for x in line:``` statement and again before the ```y==x`` statement.